# Getting error trying to launch react-native android application, JAVA_HOME is not set, no java command could be found in your path

Tags: java, android, windows, react-native

I've been trying to launch a basic app using react native. So far, I've followed the guide here, https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, for react-native CLI quickstart. I'm using Windows, and using bash with Windows linux subsystem (ubuntu)

I've launched metro, but when I try the command,

`npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier`

I get the following error,

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"

I've tried setting a path to the JRE location used by Android Studio, and also setting the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241, restarted etc.

Any insights?

I should add, when I try to launch the app through android studio (on an emulator) it gives this error,

> Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME but also, consider adding the bin to the PATH system variable

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin

Find more information here https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. I added that to the path but I still get the same error when I try to launch the app